# Combining rows by key and expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table

```
email::string
location::string
day_1::boolean
day_2::boolean
...
```

Now I need to get for each `email` `OR` of days. For the following input

```
user1@gmail.com | location1 | true  | false
user1@gmail.com | location2 | false | true
```

I want to get

```
user1@gmail.com | true  | true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT email, bool_or(day_1) AS day_1, bool_or(day_2) AS day_2 FROM your_table GROUP BY email
```